# iterate through unordered_map using boost_foreach

Tags: c++, boost

In my class I've got such `soundmap`

```
class SoundSubSystem
{
private:
    boost::unordered_map<string, ISoundEngine*> soundmap;
....
};
```

But how to iterate through it using `BOOST_FOREACH`?

```
SoundSubSystem::~SoundSubSystem()
{
    BOOST_FOREACH(/*?*/ item, soundmap) {
        item.second->drop();
    }
};
```

What value type should `item` have?

Comment: Just as an advice, consider upgrading your compiler to a version that offers C++11 support, and use a range-based `for` loop: `for (auto& item : soundmap) { item.second->drop(); }`.

Comment: I'm using visual studio 2010 - as far as I know it does not support c++11

Comment: Indeed it does not support C++11's range-based `for` loop, but it does support `auto`. So you can do: `BOOST_FOREACH(auto& item, soundmap) { item.second->drop(); }`.

Comment: I see.
Yes! It works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :-

```
typedef boost::unordered_map<string, ISoundEngine*> myhash;

BOOST_FOREACH(myhash::value_type& item, soundmap) {
        item.second->drop();
    }
```

Comment: @user1432980 Could you try it with `typename` keyword. I wonder if `BOOST_FOREACH` macro might need that for such type. OR can use `auto` as suggested in one of the comment

Comment: I'm afraid the problem here is with the comma that separates `string` from `ISoundEngine*`. Remember `BOOST_FOREACH` is a macro, so the `, ISoundEngine* ...` part will likely be interpreted as a second argument - I think. Rather use `BOOST_FOREACH(auto& item, soundmap)` or, if you really want to go the C++03 way, define a `typedef` for `boost::unordered_map<string, ISoundEngine*>` or `boost::unordered_map<string, ISoundEngine*>::value_type` outside the macro.